# Judgecode -- Array Prefix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, jobs

The problem I've seen is as below, anyone has some idea on it?

http://judgecode.com/problems/1002

Given a non-empty array of N integers A, please find the smallest integer P such that all the numbers in A are in the subarray A[0..P].

Comment: See, the idea behind those puzzles is that you work them out yourself. Asking for the answer kind of defeats the purpose of the puzzle, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to scan all the items of the array, you have to implement at least `O(N)` algorithm. I suggest scanning the array while adding into a *hash set*, when the hash set size increased (i.e. a *unique* item added), memorize the index of the item. Return the last index memorized

C# implementation:

```
private static int MinIndex(IEnumerable<int> source) {
  HashSet<int> used = new HashSet<int>();

  int index = -1;
  int result = -1;

  foreach (int item in source) {
    index += 1;

    if (used.Add(item)) // unique item added
      result = index;   // the last unique item's index so far
  }

  return result;
}
```

Test

```
int[] sample = new [] { 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, }; 

Console.Write(MinIndex(sample));
```

Outcome is `3`: all the distinct items of the initial array `{0, 1, 2}` are in the subarray `[0..3]` which is `[2, 2, 1, 0]`